# while i am migrating the database in room,it is showing error

Tags: migration, android-room

I am migrating the room db from version 2 to 3.but it is showing error like

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle user_info_job(com.nsas.bharatnext.DataBase.JobUserInfoTable).
     Expected:

TableInfo{name='user_info_job', columns={sl_no=Column{name='sl_no', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_PIN_code=Column{name='user_PIN_code', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_email=Column{name='user_email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_door_no=Column{name='user_door_no', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_name=Column{name='user_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_diploma=Column{name='user_diploma', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id_val=Column{name='id_val', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, user_specialisation=Column{name='user_specialisation', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_city=Column{name='user_city', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_gender=Column{name='user_gender', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_date_of_birth=Column{name='user_date_of_birth', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_marital_status=Column{name='user_marital_status', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_ward=Column{name='user_ward', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_state=Column{name='user_state', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_educational_qualification=Column{name='user_educational_qualification', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_mobile_num=Column{name='user_mobile_num', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_course=Column{name='user_course', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_12th=Column{name='user_12th', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_locality=Column{name='user_locality', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_sub_city=Column{name='user_sub_city', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_street_name=Column{name='user_street_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_caste=Column{name='user_caste', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, user_10th=Column{name='user_10th', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, job_sl_no=Column{name='job_sl_no', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

@Database(entities ={UserInfoTable.class,JobUserInfoTable.class,PolicyUserInfoTable.class,WorkForYouTable.class,UserDetailsTable.class},version = 3,exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converter.class})
public abstract class MyAppDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

```
public abstract MyDao myDao();

public abstract UserDAO userDAO();

public static MyAppDataBase mInstance;

public static MyAppDataBase getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance!=null){
        mInstance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,MyAppDataBase.class,"userdb")
                 .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
                 .build();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE work_for_you_info (state TEXT, city TEXT, consistency TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(slno))");
    }

};
public static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE user_info_job");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE user_info_policy");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE work_for_you_info");
        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE user_details (user_sl_no TEXT,name TEXT, email TEXT, mobile_num TEXT," +
                        "date_of_birth TEXT,religion TEXT, caste TEXT, subCaste TEXT," +
                        "occupation TEXT,state TEXT, district TEXT, constituency TEXT," +
                        "village TEXT,ward TEXT, gender TEXT, marital_status TEXT," +
                        "door_no TEXT,street_name TEXT, locality TEXT, PIN_code TEXT," +
                        "educational_qualification TEXT,course TEXT, specialisation TEXT, disabled TEXT," +
                        "userRelation TEXT)");
    }

};
```

}

Comment: anyone please help me with solution